# Spotify Web API: How to find playlists the user can edit

Tags: spotify

I'm using the endpoint

`GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists`

Is there a way to check if the logged in user (me) is allowed to modify each of the playlists?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An application can modify a playlist on a user's behalf if

- The playlist is owned by the user.
- The user has given the application the permission to do so by giving it the `playlist-modify-public` or `playlist-modify-private` scopes. Read more about scopes in the [Using Scopes](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/using-scopes/) guide.

The response from the [Get a List of a User's Playlists endpoint](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-list-users-playlists/) will look exactly the same regardless of which of the playlists that can be modified. Your application can however figure out if a playlist *can* be modified since it should know if the two requirements listed above are true or false.

**Edit:** To clarify, an application **cannot** modify a collaborative playlist that's owned by a different user than the user who it's acting on behalf of.

Comment: Thank you! Can an application also edit a collaborative playlist if it is not owned by the user?

Comment: No, it can't. Updated my response.